# JQuery mobile table is not aligned perfectly in portrait view

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

The table with dynamic value  is perfectly aligned in landscape but it is not viewing perfectly in portrait as the  respective last column is shown out of the display of the mobile.

```
   <table id="dataTable" cellspacing="0"  width="100%" cellpadding="0"
                        align="center">
       <thead>
  <tr>

<th width="25%">Name</th>
<th width="25%">Relationship</th>
<th width="25%">HomePhone</th>
<th width="25%">Email</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <tr>
  <?php $loop=1;    foreach($this->userobjArray as $temp){   ?>


                                <td align="center"  class="name"><?php echo $temp->name;?></td>
                                <td align="center" class="relation"><?php echo $temp->relation;?></td>
                                <td align="center" class="homephone"><?php echo $temp->homephone;?></td>
                                <td align="center" class="email"><?php echo $temp->email?></td>
                                <td align="center" class="id" style="display: none;"><?php echo $temp->id; ?></td>
                        </tr>

                                 <?php $loop++;  } ?> </tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Can you ask specific question, please?

Comment: @PLB Check the question again

Comment: Have you tried to add scrollbar?

Comment: @PLB how to add scrollbar in html

Comment: @PLB Eventhough i add scrollbar it is not coming

Comment: @PLB if i use css style="overflow:scroll" the value is not getting displayed

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/is-data-scroll-true-active-in-jquery-mobile try this